# Alpstein/Route-me annotation balloon

Tags: objective-c, route-me, popup-balloons

I'm using Alpstein/Route-me to work with map in my iPhone application. I want a balloon (something like MKAnnotationView, I think) to appear when I tap on marker on the map. Is there any ways to do it with Alpstein Route-me?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to define a subclass to `RMMapLayer`. `RMMapLayer`s are used to present annotations on the map like a `MKAnnotationView` is the visual representation of a `MKAnnotation`. A good starting point is probably the `RMMarker` class, which is a subclass of `RMMapLayer` and is used to present markers on the map.

Depending on the style the balloon is supposed to appear you might also be able to simply catch a tap on a marker in your map view controller. The map view informs its delegate about a tap by invoking

```
- (void)tapOnAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation 
                  onMap:(RMMapView *)mapView
```

When a tap occurs you can replace the annotation by an annotation that shows the balloon.